Shower won’t drain properly. I could hear the toilet water gurgling when I was in the shower
This has been happening over the past year. The house is 12 years old. When I’m in the shower, I have to tap my foot on the drain continuously to make the water go down. I had a plumber come in and he used to snake in the shower and said everything was clear, didn’t know why the toilet water was gurgling, but it keeps happening. I read in another post where there is a vent on top of the roof that will let air escape so it drains properly, but can you tell me what the vent looks like? I want to call the plumber back and tell him what to do. He evidently didn’t want to get on the roof because he knew it wasn’t draining properly when he left .

Consider giving your plumber a gift subscription to diy.stackexchange.com. And find a new plumber.

The vent through the roof is usually a 3 or 4 inch diameter black plastic round pipe.
